# Proving triangles congruent with circles

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I have a proof that looks like the following, not really sure where to start/how to solve. Any help would be appreciated.

Given: circle $S$ and circle $T$ intersect at $M$ and $O$.
Prove: $\triangle MST \cong \triangle OST$

[image]

Comment: What methods of proving triangle congruence do you know?

Comment: There's no proof to verify! I've replaced the "proof verification" tag: use it when you have sketched out/written a proof and you want some "eyes" to look it over/check your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the side ST is common to both triangles so you have a side in common.

Next, consider what you know about the lengths of SM and SO. What about the lengths of MT and TO? They both are the radius of the circles. Then you could use the [Side-Side-Side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28geometry%29#Determining_congruence) to show congruence. Perhaps there is another way to use the angles here for an alternative but this seems rather straightforward if S and T are the center of each circle.

Comment: Alright, I understand how you got SSS, and I was thinking about the same thing. ST is congruent to itself, so that's one side down. I know both SM and SO and congruent, and MT and TO are congruent, but I can't find what theorem proves it. It isn't definition of circle, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is the definition of circle that the curve is the set of points that are an equal distance from a center.